# Method is incorrect in exception when locating elements by ID - Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I have an odd issue in selenium.
I try to locate element by id, however if it is not located the exception is about css selector?
how it can be?

Code you can see find by ID:

```
  public static void waitForElementSeenAndClick (String elementId)
    {

        WebDriver driver2 = WebDriverMgr.getDriver();

        Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver2)
                .withTimeout(FLUENT_WAIT_MAX, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(FLUENT_WAIT_PULLING, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class,
                        Exception.class);

        wait.until(new Function<WebDriver , Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply (WebDriver driver2) {

                WebElement element = driver2.findElement(By.id(elementId));
                System.out.println("Try to click_1");
                element.click();
                if(element.isDisplayed()) {
                    System.out.println("Try to click_2");
                    element.click();
                    return true;
                }
                System.out.println("Try to click_3");
                return  false;
            }

        });
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
Wed Oct 23 17:33:45 IDT 2019:ERROR: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#header\-account\-logout"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'PC', ip: '10.6.6.3', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 77.0.3865.120, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0..., userDataDir: C:\Users\AppData\Local...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51842}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 975ad4ceb6ccdfcffd98eea965a5ad99
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=header-account-logout}

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for com.blinkx.rx.ui.common.abstractionLayer.BasePage$3@496a31da (tried for 20 second(s) with 2000 milliseconds interval)
```

> *** Element info: {Using=id, value=header-account-logout} method":"css selector

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: what id the element id which you are passing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the [W3C WebDriver Specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) was developed, the working group removed the separate locator strategy for finding elements by ID. The reason is that `By.id("foo")` is functionally equivalent to `By.cssSelector("#foo")`. The working group rightly pointed out that the Selenium language bindings could maintain the `By.id` API for locators, but translate them to the correct CSS selector under the covers. That is why you’re seeing a note about CSS selectors even when finding by ID.

Comment: OK so this means everything is clear now. since it is working OK, but when get exception mentioned css and not id. regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to click with JavascriptExecutor? May be it will work.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;          
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", lelement);
```